# Actions on Google - SendTyping response

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to improve the user experience of my application.  One UX improvement would be to reply to the user after they initialize the intent. What i would like to do is simulate the "Typing" reply, so the experience would be for a voice enabled device

User: Who's the league leader in wins?
Assistant: Give me a second to do some investigation
Assistant: Ok, John Doe is currently leading with 10 wins.

Is there a way to send multiple responses for one request.

I am using API.AI and a webhook for fulfillment. I know that i can send multiple items in one response, but i would need to send multiple responses.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, no this isn't possible.

However, at Google I/O they've indicated that they understand this is something people are looking for. There are already some solutions that have been announced that are coming (such as notifications), and there may be others coming as well.

Comment: Thanks, will move this down the line for future implementation then